# Desktop like Transition effect in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, animation, css-transitions

Im wanting to create a navigation slide animation effect in my HTML web application. Im just wondering if it is possible.

Scenario is: Page 1 = Contacts Listing, Page 2 = Contact Details.

When the user selects a contact in the listing and clicks details I want the contact listing to slide off to the left and the Contact Details slides in from the right (like an iOS navigation app).

Is this possible? The Contact Listing and Details are two seperate web pages.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is to use Jquery mobile transitions. That framework is really close to the UI of iOS

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-transitions.html

But you have to be more clear what you mean by separate webpages.
You can use iframes,anchor tags, or even ajax calls if you are using dynamic content.

Personally I really prefer the Jquery's mobile approach.
Each "page" is wrapped in divs with page markups in a single html document, also it is possible to load additional html pages with different transition effects

Take a look at this example
http://jsfiddle.net/4Bgx7/2648/

Comment: No each page is a seperate "page" i.e. Different hyperlink (not # hash clientside routing). But still want to give the effect of a smooth transition. I know there will be a slight clunk between transition with the actual page load, but once the pages are in cache than this clunk should be minor.

Comment: Check out the caching methodology of jquery mobile
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html

I recommend to avoid using separate since you want to have no lag.
If you want to avoid jquery mobile take a look at this neat example
http://www.fasw.ws/faswwp/non-jquery-page-transitions-lightweight/